# Perl debuging causes: An internal error occurred during: "PerlDebugJob"

Tags: eclipse, perl, debugging, carp

I didn't know what I do wrong. When I debug my perl script, it was terminated. Place where scipr is terminated is completely normal return from the function:

```
sub new {

    my $self = shift;
    $self = {};
    bless $self;

    #instance of  "base" class Features.pm
    $self->{"base"} = Features->new();

    my @features = ();
    $self->{"features"} = \@features;

    return $self; # <== here is script terminated
}
```

Right before terminated it goes to `Carp` module to function `longmess`
I put here only preview of my code, because it is huge project. Only to see how the ordinary code it is, where it fail.

When I "remove" the module, which leads to termanation, from project and run this module separately, it is OK. Thus error will be somewhere else.

[image]
(this error happend in different places in code, but only in `return` command)
I use perl 5.16, Eclipse and Epic and my project located in c:\Perl\site\lib\

Please help me. Thank you

**EDIT**

Problem occurs only when I run program in debug mode in eclipse. When I run it without debuging

Comment: The link to your screenshot is broken. Please don't include screenshots of code or error messages, but instead provide them as text in the question body. You can [edit] your question and change that. You should also include a bit more of that program you wrote. If I copy and run your code snippet, it won't do anything because it's just a function that's not invoked anywhere. And we don't have Features either. Without the full thing, we cannot reproduce your problem and thus can't help.

Comment: I don't think this is about the `return`. Does this problem also occur when you run your program without a debugger? Or with the command line debugger (just run it with `perl -d foo.pl`)? I believe this is Eclipse getting confused with your file system.

Comment: Problem occurs only when I run program in debug mode in eclipse. When I run it without debuging OR simply from console OR with `perl -d foo.pl` everything is Ok. So what I shoul do? What do you mean by "Eclipse getting confused with your file system"?

Comment: Have you read the error messages down in the bottom left pane? It complains that it doesn't like some paths. I have no clue what that means, but it sounds like it's confused there. On the other hand, it opened the right file, didn't it?